# PowerShell - Create an array that ignores duplicate values

Tags: arrays, powershell, duplicates

Curious if there a construct in PowerShell that does this?

I know you can do this:

```
$arr = @(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4)
$arr = $arr | Get-Unique
```

But seems like performance-wise it would be better to ignore the value as you are entering it into the array instead of filtering out after the fact.

Comment: So what's the question? If you want a data structure that guarantees no duplicates, then use a hashtable rather than an array. (A hashtable, by definition, cannot have duplicate keys.)

Comment: I’d go for the hash table as well. Easy to use, and nice performance. That being said, it might be cheaper to insert the dublicates and then remove them when you need to read the data. Things done in bulk by an optimized algorithm (like sort -unique) can be much cheaper for the system than you own code in the enterpreter. Generally: go for readability and only focus on performance when you are able to measure a bottleneck.

Comment: `$arr|Sort-Object -Unique -CaseSensitive`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If are you inserting a large number of items in to an array (thousands) the performance does drop, because the array needs to be reinitialized every time you add to it so it may be better in your case, performance wise, to use something else.

Dictionary, or HashTable could be a way.  Your single dimensional unique array could be retrieved with $hash.Keys For example:

```
$hash = ${}
$hash.Set_Item(1,1)
$hash.Set_Item(2,1)
$hash.Set_Item(1,1)
$hash.Keys
1
2
```

If you use Set_Item, the key will be created or updated but never duplicated.  Put anything else for the value if you're not using it,  But maybe you'll have a need for a value with your problem too.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use an Arraylist:

```
     Measure-Command -Expression {
    $bigarray = $null
    $bigarray =  [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $bigarray = (1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4)
    $bigarray | select -Unique
}
```

Time passed:

- TotalSeconds      : 0,0006581
- TotalMilliseconds : 0,6581

  ```
   Measure-Command -Expression {
  $array = @(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4)
  $array | select -Unique
  }
  ```

Time passed:

- TotalSeconds      : 0,0009261
- TotalMilliseconds : 0,9261

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it compares performance-wise, but the HashSet collection is an array that requires unique values.

```
$arr = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]]::new()
3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4 | &{process{
  [void]$arr.Add($_)
}}
"$arr" #returns: 1 2 3 4
```

If you want it to be automatically sorted as well, replace "HashSet" with "SortedSet".